# Get value from script to var in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I Have This Script:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

&&

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       geoplugin_countryName();
       geoplugin_countryCode();

</script>
```

this fun

```
@{
var current = Model.Where(f => f.CurrentRegion == "CurrentRegion" );
}
```

How can i make (CurrentRegion) = geoplugin_countryCode();
Note that the other does not work outside the script

```
@ViewBag.CurrentRegion = geoplugin_countryCode(); ///// Does not bring value
```

The name of this great website in value in the meaning of the need to ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work that way because the c# code in your view gets executed in the server while your javascript executes in the client side.

What you can do is keep 2 pages, In page1, execute your javascript and get the country code from your javascript function, then use that as a querystring param to naivgate to second page(Action method) where you will accept this country code in a parameter and do whatever you want.

So in your first page(view),

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" 
                                                          type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 var countryCode = geoplugin_countryCode();
 window.location.href="@Url.Action("SecondPage","YourControllerName")?country=" + 
                                                                           countryCode'
</script>
```

and the SecondPage action method

```
public ActionResult SecondPage(string country)
{
  //  use country to populate your view model
  //  to do : return something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to POST this information back to the controller or make an AJAX request to a local web service that would know how to process the information.

Using JavaScript you can store the information in hidden input fields on the page and then POST that information back with page data you are submitting normally.